# Reloading UITableView after unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a settings TableViewController which presents the information of the user, like name and email. The user can edit these settings by tapping the edit button at the navigation bar, which shows another TableViewController. After editing the user can press "save" which triggers an unwind segue to the first view. The problem is, the table view won't update. I tried putting:

```
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

in the viewDidLoad() and the viewDidAppear() and I tried putting:

```
    let vc = segue.identifier as! FirstTableViewController
    vc.tableView.reloadData()
```

in the prepareForSegue and also in the action of the save button.

The strange thing is after editing the second time and saving the tableview updates to the first edit.

The inputted data by the user is saved in NSUserDefaults and in the viewDidLoad() of the tableView, this data is fetched and assigned to labels in the tableView.

I also have this problem with reloading a tableView after the user created an invoice and when the user taps finish to unwind to the tableView which shows all the invoices.

I would be very happy if someone would know a solution to this.

Comment: Where are you saving the data after it is edited and saved? Are you updating the same model that you are using to load the table view?

Comment: *"I tried putting: `self.tableView.reloadData()` ..."* In any of the places that you tried that, did it actually trigger a table data reload? If so, and the table doesn't "update," then it sounds like you have not updated your DataSource / model prior to returning to the first view. If it *doesn't* trigger the reload, then that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Exactly what @PGDev says.. you're probably not updating your datasource. Reloading the tableView is not going to change it unless your data model has changed.

Comment: A bit more code is probably needed for you to get some help. How is the user stored in the general TableViewController? How are the changes made  to the user propagated back to that view controller when the "save" button is pushed? Are you using reusable cells?

Comment: I am saving the data in NSUserDefaults and fetching this data in the viewDidLoad() and assigning it to labels.

Comment: After saving the updated data in NSUserDefaults, you need to fetch it again in viewWillAppear of tableView controller before reloading the tableView. Just move your fetching work to viewWillAppear to avoid redundancy. Alternatively, you can use closure to update the model on tableView controller and then reload data.